# Meaning of 'of other'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across [a paragraph](https://southasia.typepad.com/south_asia_daily/2018/05/nehru-science-and-religion.html) in which, I'm not sure about the usage of 'other.'

> It was obvious that there was a vast unknown region all around us, and science, with its magnificent achievements, knew little enough about it, though it was making tentative approaches in that direction. Probably also, the normal methods of science, its dealings with the visible world and the processes of life, were not wholly adapted to the physical, the artistic, the spiritual, and other elements of the invisible world. Life does not consist entirely of what we see and hear and feel, the visible world which is undergoing change in time and space; it is continually touching an invisible world ***of other***, and possibly more stable or equally changeable elements, and no thinking person can ignore this invisible world.

Is this can be parsed the following way?

...invisible world of other more stable and equally unchangeable elements. But  **and possibly more stable or equally changeable elements,** is a defining clause.

Answer (score 1):

> Life is continually touching an invisible world of other, and possibly more stable or equally changeable elements, and no thinking person can ignore this invisible world.

I would parse the meaning thus:

> Life is continually touching an invisible world of other elements. These elements are possibly more stable or they might be equally changeable. No thinking person can ignore this invisible world.